# Caret glm logistic regression type = "response?"

Tags: r, logistic-regression, r-caret, glm

I would like to retrieve the predicted probabilities from a logistic regression via caret.

According to [this](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/predict.glm.html) documentation on ""type  parameter:

> "the type of prediction required. The default is on the scale of the
>   linear predictors; the alternative "response" is on the scale of the
>   response variable. Thus for a default binomial model the default
>   predictions are of log-odds (probabilities on logit scale) and type =
>   "response" gives the predicted probabilities. The "terms" option
>   returns a matrix giving the fitted values of each term in the model
>   formula on the linear predictor scale.".

Using caret I tried:

```
  predict(quadratic_model.rds,
          newdata = some_df,
          type = "response")})
```

This returned error:

> "Error in predict.train(quadratic_model, newdata = some_df, type =
>   "response") :    type must be either "raw" or "prob""

When I use "prob" instead of response a result is returned and each value is between zero and 1. Is this the log odds or the regular probability?

Comment: `"prob"` should be the probability, I think. Log odds is not restricted to [0, 1]. The reason the options don't match the documentation is that caret is probably using something other than `glm` to fit the logistic regression, you'd have to check what `caret` is doing.

Comment: How did you create the `quadratic_model.rds` object? It’s easier to help you with a reproducible example.

Comment: did anyone get feedback on this? i used the caret, but i also want the "response" , not the probability, nor the binary assessments from "raw"

Comment: @ElChapo afraid not and I cannot recall what I ended up doing here. I might have used glm directly outside of caret. Sorry cannot be more helpful